# Content in WKWebview not readjusting its size when device is rotated

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, autoresizingmask

I am using WkWebView which works as expected. But when I rotate the device WkWebView is expanding to the screen size but the content inside the webview is not resizing.

I have seen other posts like : 
[WKWebView added as Subview is not resized on rotation in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30737254/wkwebview-added-as-subview-is-not-resized-on-rotation-in-swift)

I am using

```
webView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
```

as many others suggested but nothing seems to work.

**Here is my code:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let preferences = WKPreferences()
    preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true

    let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    config.processPool = GlobalVariables.myWebPool

    let contentController =  WKUserContentController()

    config.userContentController = contentController
    contentController.add(self, name: "appInterface")

    webView = WKWebView(frame: webContainer.bounds, configuration:  config)
    webView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

    if let theWebView = webView{

        let urlString = "https:www.xyz"
        let myUrl = URL(string: urlString)
        myRequest = URLRequest(url: myUrl!)

        setCookie(key: "ASP.NET_SessionId", value:GlobalVariables.cookieValue)

        theWebView.navigationDelegate = self
        webContainer.addSubview(theWebView)

        self.webView?.load(self.myRequest)
    }
}
```

Comment: [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33509128/9333764) may be a solution to your problem. It is to dynamically set the content size of the webview

Comment: You'd want to tinker a bit but that should get you off to a good start.

Comment: @Jake The answer which you have posted is for UIWebView and Sindhu is asking for WKWebView.

Comment: Ah, I missed that. Thanks for keeping an eye out!

Comment: @Jake's comment above has been updated to WKWebView and Swift 5